# Button In Kotlin will not work in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, button

So I'm trying to create a tabbed app in Kotlin and I have chosen the default one they made for you to practice but I can't figure out how to get the buttons working `

```
package com.example.android_app.ui.home

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.android_app.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*


class HomeFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Program Buttons
        logout.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, sign_in::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        })
        return root
    }
}
`
```

As far as I know this should work. The problem is not in the button but in Intent. My button is already defined and has no errors but there is a red line under Intent even though it's imported. The error message is below.

public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent

public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

Comment: You shouldn't import `activity_main.*` into your Fragment

Comment: sign_in::class.java This needs to be a class, it looks like a xml resource.

Comment: Chenge this to this@HomeFragment

Comment: That is not the full error message

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `context` into the constructor of Intent instead of `this`.

```
val intent = Intent(context, sign_in::class.java)
```